# Adding arguments to -c flag on forever start

Tags: node.js, forever

I'm trying to pass arguments with forever, not going very well:

```
> NODE_PATH="$(pwd)" NODE_ENV=production forever start -c "node app.js --site=tillvaxt"

help:    usage: forever [action] [options] SCRIPT [script-options]
...//more help options displayed
```

I'm using the `-c` flag as you can see. Is this correct? Debugging in Forever isn't the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

try to export instead of set. Like this

```
 export NODE_PATH="$(pwd)" && export NODE_ENV=production && forever start -c "node app.js --site=tillvaxt"
```

With export you're forcing the that envvars gets "injected"  on the next conmmand started from the current shell